# Calling functions present in a different file in R

Tags: r, function

I want my R code to be organised into different files. I have done done that but I am not able to call a function present in another file from my current file. I know it would be a simple thing... It would be great if someone can pen down a response.

file1: test1.R contains

```
`func1<-function(){
    ....
}`
```

file2: test2.R contains

```
func2<-function(){
    func1();
}
```

Both files are in same directory
I get an error : func1 doesn't exist

Is there something like C,Cpp like include statement in R

Comment: if you vote down, also comment why you are doing so

Comment: Please add a few more details and a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Do you use `source` to load your files? Sounds like a path problem.

Comment: I have not used source @sgibb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are after `source`:

```
source("func1.R")
```

The functions in that file should now appear in your workspace:

```
ls()
```